# How old was Amon when his son Josiah was born?

Tags: kings, judah

2 Kings 21:19 says Amon was 22 years old when he became king over Judah and reigned only 2 years and was put to death. 2 Kings 22:1 says Josiah was 8 years old when he became King over Judah. Was Amon only 16 whan Josiah was born? Or was there a period of time between Amon's death and Josiah's being inagurated as king?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "yes", it appears that from 2 Kings 21:19 and 22;1, Amon was about 16 when Josiah was born.  This was the culture at the time - kings married quite early and produced children at a young age.

The king Josiah was similar to the above:

- Josiah was eight years old when he became king, 2 Kings 22:1
- Josiah reigned for 31 years, 2 Kings 22:1
- Therefore, Josiah was about 39 when he died
- Josiah's son, Jehoahaz was 23 years old when he became king at the death of his father, 2 Kings 23:30, 31
- Therefore, Josiah was about 16 years old when his son was born.

A similar analysis could be done for several other kings showing similar results.

Comment: thanks Just affirming